# Nginx rewrite rule issue to remove end of url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to remove .mp4 from `www.foo.com/bar/rab/video.mp4`

So I am left with `www.foo.com/bar/rab/video`

So far I have

```
location ~* ^/bar/rab/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/bar/rab/(.*)$/$(.mp4) /$1/$2 break;
    proxy_pass https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

However I think I am miles wrong, could anyone please explain and help me

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
location ~* ^/bar/(.*).mp4$ {
    rewrite ^/bar/(.*).mp4 /bar/$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

Here's something about Perl-compatible Regular Expressions which is what nginx uses:

http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/~heckendo/CS445/regex.html

Here's a regex tester:

http://www.regextester.com/

So if you stick "^/bar/(.*).mp4" in the regex field (the first part of the rewrite), and put "/bar/rab/foo.mp4" in the text field, and then put "/bar/$1" in the replace-with field (the second part of the rewrite), you will get "/bar/rab/foo" as expected.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you have a look again please :)

Comment: Well, you can just modify the pattern to have /rab in there.  On the other hand, the pattern match is broad enough so that it will probably work as is.  Why don't you try it?